# Visual Studio 2013 inline color picker

Tags: visual-studio-2013, color-picker

Does anyone know about a Visual Studio 2013 extension or an IDE option highlights (underscores) the color structure right in the code editor and lets you call the color picker (popup window) to choose a color visually? The point is that I saw this functionality accidentally but I do not know how to enable this in my IDE at home.

This should look like on the picture presented below:

[image: Color inline picker]

Comment: Unfortunately, I've googled almost the whole web, tried many extensions and couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does support this.

Comment: No. I've tried ReSharper. It just underscores the color name instead of Color and let you choose colors only when you are typing as a part of autocompletion.

Comment: Yes, it does. At least for CSS but that extension is for VS 2012 only. But I saw the functionality exactly for VS 2013

Comment: It's too sad. Two unexplained downvotes and none of useful answers to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.
At last, I've found the answer to my question.

This is the color picker extension from "DevExpress CodeRush for Visual Studio":

1) [Working with Color in CodeRush](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2010/04/26/working-with-color-in-coderush.aspx)

2) [DevExpress CodeRush](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/F9CDA5D8-10AF-4CC6-9D17-207222A3FD13)

Answer (score 3):

You can enable this option from ReSharper, in Resharper options in the settings tab, the option Usages Highlight Color

[Documentation about this option](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Color_Assistance.html)

Update: Extension for a selection of color friendly

[Inline Color Picker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/86afb3bf-e14e-4a35-817e-4580a95cf33c)

Comment: Thank you, Rudel, for your answer, but I know about this feature in ReSharper and, as I've said in my comment above, the feature I seek for is not that in ReSharper. First, ReSharper highlights color values instead of the Color type (as shown on the picture above). Second, the extension I need highlights the Color type itself with a color band underneath and allows to call popup color picker window by mouse clicking on that band. Anyway, thank you again for your trying to help me.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand you well, the extension you need is Inline Color Picker.  I think that it is what you need

Comment: No, Rudel. I've tried the Inline Color Picker extension and it does not provide source code highlighting in editor window at all. It only helps you pick colors in Design mode.

Comment: Arlen, i have ReSharper 8.1 and when i complete de color, y have a list of colors with the color underscore. What is your version of resharper?

Comment: Does it let you choose a color by mouse clicking on the color band?

Comment: You have an autocomplete list of colors, and you can select one. With mouse or with keys.

Comment: Yes, I have. But, as I've said in one of my comment above it's really able to autocomplete colors but the point is that it is not the functionality I need. I need exactly the behavior I've described in my topic since I know that extension exists. Moreover, the ReSharper extension is not free and I prefer to revise free versions first. :)